# CSRF verification failed - Request aborted

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-1.10

I am getting the CSRF failure in Django and no articles are working.
It says it's used for posts like I remember, and it is included in the form, but not in a form tag.

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<h1>Login</h1>

<form id="login_form" method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Username</span>
        <input type="text"class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="username" value="" size="50" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Password</span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />
    </div>
     <br>
    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
        <input class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<br /><br />
<a style="font-size:22px;" href="/accounts/register/">Need to make a new account?</a>


{% endblock %}

{% block buttons %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('bookmarks:silo')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Sitename account is disabled.")

        else:
            return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', locals(), context)
    else:

        template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
        return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', locals(), context)
```

Why is this csrf token not working?

Comment: Which version of django you are using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **RequestContext** with parameter **context_instance** like this :

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('bookmarks:silo')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Sitename account is disabled.")

        else:
            return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', context_instance = context, locals(), )
    else:

        template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
        return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', context_instance = context, locals(), context)
```

One more thing, **context_instance** is deprecated since **Django 1.8**.
You can just use :

```
 return render(request,'accounts/login.html', locals())
```